# Is it wrong to alter the value keyword within a setter?

Tags: c#

I have a setter that needs to process the new value with the old value.
However if the value is < 0.1 it needs to be set to 0.1.

I could create a newValue variable based on the value keyword but this seems a bit wasteful and within the processing section it is not immediately obvious what newValue is.

Likewise if I looked at the code I would expect 'value' to be what was passed to the setter rather than something manipulated.

What would be the best way to write this, use newValue or the value keyword?

```
public double NumberValue
{
    get => _numberValue;
    set
    {
        if (value < 0.1) value = 0.1;

        var multiplier = value / _numberValue;
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            item.SomeValue = item.SomeValue * multiplier;
        }
        _numberValue = value;
    }
}
```

My method has ended up like this which is a much neater solution

```
public double NumberValue
{
    get { return _numberValue; }
    set
    {                
        var newValue = Math.Max(0.1, value);
        ProcessValues(newValue);
        _numberValue = newValue;        
    }
}
```

Comment: If the property uses a value-type (int,byte,double,simple datatype) and not a reference-type (string,any class or collection) you are can do to that value whatever you want. but i would use @lewis approache that he posted as answer in this case, this is short and still very good readable

Comment: "this seems a bit wasteful" - are you using a weird version of the compiler where you have to *pay* for each variable declaration? Any method (property setter or not) that makes changes to its arguments is generally "allowed" but can make things significantly more difficult to understand if you're trying to *debug* them.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  Ha, it was more that if I did use another variable it would not be quite so obvious and readable as the value keyword

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```
public double NumberValue
{
    get => _numberValue;
    set
    {
        _numberValue = value < 0.1 ? 0.1 : value;
    }
}
```

Another way suggested by @Matthew in the comments would be to use [`Math.Max`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.max?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Math_Max_System_Double_System_Double_):

```
public double NumberValue
{
    get => _numberValue;
    set
    {
        _numberValue = Math.Max(0.1, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do need to do a small amount of processing with backing field before I can set it.

Comment: Could also use `Math.Max(0.1,value)` in place of ternary operator. Functionally the same, just comes down to preference.

Comment: Good one @Matthew! I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: @MattNorrie Can you edit your question to include all of your requirements? I'd be happy to update my answer if you could clarify what other processing you need to do. You could always extract that processing into a method.

Comment: I've updated the question, I think the extracting the processing into a method is probably the right thing to do

Answer (score 3):

Technically, it really doesn't matter. What differences there are are about readability.

Here, I'd probably do `_numberValue = value < 0.1 ? 0.1 : value;` myself because all of the logic is clear and this rather idiomatic statement covers everything.

If the logic was more complicated then I might favour overwriting `value` or I might favour declaring a new variable based on just how much more complicated it is. In particular I might favour a new variable if there was more than a page of code so it wasn't clear while looking at the bottom of the setter that `value` had been overwritten.

In favour of overwriting also is that it's a matter of clamping `value` to within a range. Some more disconnected possible uses of overwriting are not going to be as readable.

As with all readability matters there isn't a perfect answer and there's always a tension between the readability advantage of being short and the readability advantage of being concise.